# Package clash between amsmath and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, amsmath

I was confronted with a problem that maybe there exists some clash between package `amsmath` and `hyperref`. An MEW is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{$\cdots$}
\end{document}
```

There is no problem using PDFlatex. But Xelatex can not pass. The error says `Improper alphabetic constant`. If one of `amsmath` or `hyperref` is deleted, or we write `\section*` instead of `\section`, the compiling with Xelatex is no problem. And also, the problem is the same if we change `\cdots` to `\dotsc,\dotsb,\dotsm,\dotso`. But `\dotsi` can pass. I really don't know why. Any advice will be appreciate.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What if you use `\section[alternative text]{origonal text}` where alternative text will be used in the table of contents,...?

Comment: Thanks! If I use `\section[$\dots$]{$\cdots$}`, the compiling is right. But the error still appears if i  use `\section[$\cdots$]{$\cdots$}`.

Comment: Use \texorpdfstring to separate the bookmark from text.

Comment: Got it! Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\texorpdfstring`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring{$\cdots$}{\textcdots}}

\end{document}
```

The `unicode` option is recommended with `xelatex`.

[image]

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Emm, I meet with another problem

```tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subsection{\texorpdfstring{$w=\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{6}n]{(z-a_1)^ {\beta_1}\cdots(z-a_m)^{\beta_m}}$}{anything is wrong}}


\end{document} 

```
There is something wrong when producing a table of contents.

Comment: @Misaya Add `\MakeRobust\leftroot` and `\MakeRobust\uproot` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: Pecfectly done, thanks again!